A geometry problem about a straight line passing through the midpoint
I have a simple geometric problem with the following simple statement. Let triangle ABC be inscribed in circle (O). P is a point in triangle ABC. Let F be the intersection of AC and (APB), E be the intersection of AB and (APC). Let Q be the intersection of AP and (O), QF intersects (O) at R. Prove that BR passes through the midpoint of EF. a problem related to midpoints, EF's midpoints looked very out of place so I tried to create some more midpoints and I have something interesting below, you can use it to solve the problem.

Let Y,Z be the midpoints CF,BE, then YAZP is inscribed in a circle.

If PA intersects (AEF) at X, then P is the midpoint of QX. To prove this, I have constructed a few more parallelograms. I will update the proof later.

Three circles (O), (AEF) and (AYZ) converge at 1 point


Please give your comments, thank you very much

If this is a simple  problem, I do not want to see a complex problem.

@prem Prove that BR passes through the midpoint of EF

@martycohen Actually, what I mean is that a problem is stated simply but in itself it is not easy at all
